# How to get a string from Powershell in a batch script (Windows)?

Tags: bash, batch, powershell, cmd.exe

I have a script that uses invoke-request to get a remote ID string. How can I retrieve the value of instanceID and set it to  (SET instanceId) within .bat script

```
powershell $instanceId =(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id).Content exit
```

TNKS

Answer (score 2):

- The variable isn't set in PoSh - but simply output.
- The batch wraps the powershell command in a parsing for /f loop and sets a batch variable.

---

```
@Echo off
For /f "usebackqdelims=" %%A in (
  `Powershell.exe -nologo -NoProfile -command "(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id).Content"`
) Do Set InstanceID=%%A
Echo InstanceID=%InstanceID%
Pause
```